# How do I check the HTTP status code and also parse the payload

Tags: bash

Imagine I have the following code in a bash script:

```
curl -s https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat | jq .
```

Notice that I wish to display the payload of the response by passing it to `jq`.

Now suppose sometimes those curls sometimes return a 404, in such cases my script currently still succeeds so what I need to do is check the return code and `exit 1` as appropriate (e.g. for a 404 or 503). I've googled around and found https://superuser.com/a/442395/722402 which suggests `--write-out "%{http_code}"` might be useful however that simply prints the http_code after printing the payload:

`curl -s --write-out "%{http_code}" https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat | jq .`

```
$ curl -s --write-out "%{http_code}" https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat | jq .  
{  
  "_id": "591f98783b90f7150a19c1ab",  
  "__v": 0,  
  "text": "Cats and kittens should be acquired in pairs whenever possible as cat families interact best in pairs.",  
  "updatedAt": "2018-12-05T05:56:30.384Z",  
  "createdAt": "2018-01-04T01:10:54.673Z",  
  "deleted": false,  
  "type": "cat",  
  "source": "api",  
  "used": false  
}  
200
```

What I actually want to is still output the payload, but still be able to check the http status code and fail accordingly. I'm a bash noob so am having trouble figuring this out. Help please?

I'm using a Mac by the way, not sure if that matters or not (I'm vaguely aware that some commands work differently on Mac)

---

Update, I've pieced this together which sorta works. I think. Its not very elegant though, I'm looking for something better.

```
func() {
   echo "${@:1:$#-1}";
}
response=$(curl -s --write-out "%{http_code}" https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat | jq .) 
http_code=$(echo $response | awk '{print $NF}')
func $response | jq .
if [ $http_code == "503" ]; then
    echo "Exiting with error due to 503"
    exit 1
elif [ $http_code == "404" ]; then
    echo "Exiting with error due to 404"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: There are some things that are just much easier to do in a different language; this is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

What about this. It uses a temporary file. Seems me a bit complicated but it separates your content.

```
# copy/paste doesn't work with the following
curl -s --write-out \
   "%{http_code}" https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat | \ 
   tee test.txt | \      # split output to file and stdout
   sed -e 's-.*\}--' | \ # remove everything before last '}'
   grep 200  && \       # try to find string 200, only in success next step is done
   echo && \            # a new-line to juice-up the output
   cat test.txt | \     # 
   sed 's-}.*$-}-' | \  # removes the last line with status
   jq                   # formmat json
```

Here a copy/paste version

```
curl -s --write-out "%{http_code}" https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat | tee test.txt | sed -e 's-.*\}--' | grep 200  && echo && cat test.txt | sed 's-}.*$-}-' | jq
```

Comment: impressive. Will have a play with that and see what I can do. thx.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt. Hope it works for you too.

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$( curl -i -s 'https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat'  )


status=$( echo "$result" | grep -E '^HTTPS?/[1-9][.][1-9] [1-9][0-9][0-9]' | grep -o ' [1-9][0-9][0-9] ')
payload=$( echo "$result" | sed -n '/^\s*$/,//{/^\s*$/ !p}' )

echo "STATUS : $status"
echo "PAYLOAD : $payload"
```

#### Output

```
STATUS :  200
PAYLOAD : {"_id":"591f98803b90f7150a19c23f","__v":0,"text":"Cats can't taste sweets.","updatedAt":"2018-12-05T05:56:30.384Z","createdAt":"2018-01-04T01:10:54.673Z","deleted":false,"type":"cat","source":"api","used":false}
```

#### AWK version

```
payload=$( echo "$result" | awk '{ if( $0 ~ /^\s*$/ ){ c_p = 1 ; next; } if (c_p) { print $0} }' )
```

Regards!

#### EDIT : I have simplified this even more by using the **-i** flag

#### EDIT II : Removed empty line from payload

#### EDIT III : Included an **awk** method to extract the payload in case **sed** is problematic

Comment: hmm, I copied and pasted, ran it and it told me `sed: 1: "/^\* Connection .* to h ...": extra characters at the end of p command`

Comment: @jamiet Please check now. I have simplified more

Comment: Matias, hugely appreciate your efforts. Unfortunately still getting a similar error: `sed: 1: "/^\s*$/,//{/^\s*$/ !p}": extra characters at the end of p command`. I'm on a Mac by the way, I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Can you tell me your **sed** version? With : **sed --version** ? On the meantime Ill workaround it without sed

Comment: hmm.... `sed --version` returns `sed: illegal option -- -`. I've tried every possible variation, they all say the same. I'm flummoxxed.

Comment: Try then with awk syntax I have just added instead of sed

Comment: tried it. `$payload` was empty :( Sorry Matias, I don't know what's going on. I swear I'm just copying/pasting your code.

Comment: Well ... That's a bummer. Maybe you can add the output of the curl command (the one I gave ) to your original question . If payload was empty but it did not erroreemd

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163484/49069) you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(curl -s --write-out "%{http_code}" https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random?animal=cat)

http_code="${result: -3}"
response="${result:0:${#result}-3}" 
echo "Response code: " $http_code
echo "Response: " 
echo $response | jq
```

Where
`${result: -3}` is the 3rd index starting from the right of the string till the end. This `${result: -3:3}` also would work: Index -3 with length 3

`${#result}` gives us the length of the string

`${result:0:${#result}-3}` from the beginning of `result` to the end minus 3 from the `http_status` code

The site `cat-fact.herokuapp.com` isn't working now so I had to test it with another site